# App to App Authentication

Tags: api, linkedin-api

So my scenario is I need to get a feed from a company page to cache and process for a internal website that will display the posts.  The problem is this is not a "User" it is an application and I don't want to associate this with my profile.

[Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens) and [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only) OAuth2 process can be done completely programatically since it is an application authorization.  However I can not see how to do this with LinkedIn, since it requires a user account, and the user to enter a password and accept the access requirements.

Any ideas on how to do this 100% programatically?

If this isn't possible is there any read only API's that are not protected via user credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not only is App to App API access not available, LinkedIn will be heavily restricting their public API moving forward start May 12th, 2015.

Source: https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for :

**https://github.com/emorikawa/linkedin-oauth2**

Comment: This is not correct.  see section https://github.com/emorikawa/linkedin-oauth2#step-2c-user-sign-in  This requires a user to sign in.